# How do I debug a Release NuGet package compiled and packed in a CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2017, nuget

The following class library projects (**.NET Framework 4.6.2**, **Release** mode) are Published to private NuGet Feed:

- Project A (contains ProjectA.dll, ProjectA.pdb)
- Project B (contains ProjectB.dll, ProjectB.pdb)
- Project C (contains ProjectC.dll, ProjectC.pdb)

The above NuGet packages are added in a single Console Application `project D` which gets compiled and executes successfully. But when tried to step-into the code in debug mode from project D, a window opens up trying to find the file ProjectAClass1.cs in the location it was compiled.

After so many searches in Internet, I added the source class files in the package by updating the nuspec file, and now the nuget package structure looks like: 
[image: nuget package structure]
src contains all of the classes. This is how the nuspec looks now:

```xml
  <files>
    <file src="ProjectA.dll" target="lib\net462" />
    <file src="ProjectA.pdb" target="lib\net462" />
    <file src="**\*.cs" target="src" />
  </files>
```

When tried to debug in Visual studio - the same thing happened: it was trying to find the ProjectAClass1.cs, so I provided the location: `D:\ProjectD\packages\ProjectA\1.0.1\src\ProjectAClass1.cs` and this time I was able to debug successfully.

But if I update the version of the nuget package, it may again prompt of the location of the class.

I am currently using SVN, TeamCity for build/publish, Visual Studio 2017.9 for debugging, a private nuget feed. I can not use symbol servers as the organisation is hesitant towards it due to security issues, and I see [sourcelink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) only [supports git](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/184) as of now.

Is it the right approach for debugging ? Or is there any other option available for debugging a class library project that is published in release mode ? Or is there any way to embedded all the classes in the DLL so that it automatically finds the classes and debugs them ?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can my answer helps to resolve it? If the issue persists to block you , feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT - after discussing with my seniors we are now using the method specified in the comment i.e. when we are publishing a nuget, we also include the *.cs files within it, and while debugging we point the source to the nuget package folder installed in the solution path. after every nuget update we manually update the path in the solution properties > debug > add debug source file

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help, do you mind accepting it as answer if I add the comment into my answer later :)

Comment: `after every nuget update we manually update the path in the solution properties > debug > add debug source file `. Maybe you can try adding install.ps1 or package_ID.targets file when creating nuget packages. Then the install.ps1 or targets file will execute when you uninstall+install or update the package. (You can write logic to copy the source files to a specific path in powershell script or msbuild xx.targets, then you only need to add the path to debug source file once)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the right approach for debugging ? Or is there any other option
>   available for debugging a class library project that is published in
>   release mode ? Or is there any way to embedded all the classes in the
>   DLL so that it automatically finds the classes and debugs them ?

I suggest you can try this approach:

1.Create a folder in local machine to store the all source files of ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC(Make sure the version of the source files match the version used to build the nuget packages)

2.In the Solution where `projectD` exists, `right-click Solution=>Properties=>Debug Source Files` to add the path of the folder.

Then when you debug `ProjectD` in VS, debugger can step into the source code since now VS debugger knows where to find the source files.

**In addition:**

If you can confirm the version of source files match the version of packed assemblies and pdbs, you can feel free to suppress the warning(`The source file is different`) by going `debug=>Options` to uncheck the `require source files to exactly match original version` option.

Comment: yes we are doing this now, but is difficult to manage the version of the class. Mostly we get message like “The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger use it anyway?”

Comment: Go debug=>Options to uncheck the `require source files to exactly match original version` can make the warning go away. But it's not a good idea... We should be careful to make sure the xx.cs file is the same version which outputs the xx.dll and xx.pdb...